# SQL subquery error

Tags: sql

Where is the error?

```
SELECT * FROM papiry 
WHERE (aktivni=1 AND pocetovereni>1 ORDER BY pocetovereni DESC LIMIT1) 
AND oddeleni='$oddeleni' ORDER BY nazev ASC;
```

Thanks for help, I'm not good at SQL.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(), sql command dont work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM papiry 
WHERE (aktivni = 1 AND pocetovereni > 1) 
AND oddeleni='$oddeleni' 
ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN ktivni = 1 AND pocetovereni > 1 THEN pocetovereni END DESC,
     CASE WHEN oddeleni='$oddeleni' THEN nazev END ASC
```

Comment: Nice, working but, if i need use LIMIT for select only 1 row with top **pocetovereni** in __CASE WHEN ktivni = 1 AND pocetovereni > 1 THEN pocetovereni END DESC__ ?

Comment: @user1612058, Do you want to get only the first top 1 `pocetovereni` then the other rows come first??

Comment: I have more rows with **nazev** and i need only one row, where is most pocetovereni.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad SQL, `ORDER BY` is not a clause to be entered within `WHERE` clauses. A potential good SQl would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM papiry 
WHERE aktivni=1 
AND pocetovereni>1 
AND oddeleni='$oddeleni' 
ORDER BY ORDER BY pocet, overeni DESC, nazev ASC;
```

However, you have to decide which columns you want to order by. That's defined at the end of the SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

Order By must appear after the WHERE-clause, this would at least work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM papiry 
WHERE aktivni=1 AND pocetovereni>1 AND oddeleni='$oddeleni' 
ORDER BY pocetovereni DESC, nazev ASC
```